# Error occurs every time trigger is fired

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I get this error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]1
>   (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers)

any time this trigger is fired:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgDR] 
   ON  [dbo].[Deceased Register]
   AFTER  INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @parishid int, @monthid int, @yearid int,@total float,@gtotal float
    select @parishid =i.Parish_id from inserted i;
    select @monthid=i.Month_id from inserted i;
    select @yearid=i.year_id from inserted i;    

    select @total=COUNT(*) from [Deceased Register] 
        where Parish_id=@parishid and Year_id=@yearid and 
        Month_id=@monthid               
        print @total
        select @gtotal=COUNT(*) from [Deceased Register] 
        where Parish_id=@parishid and Year_id=@yearid 
        print @total

        if not exists(select parish_id from ParishStatistics 
        where parish_id=@parishid and Year_id=@yearid and month_id=@monthid)
        begin
            insert into ParishStatistics (Parish_id,Year_id,month_id,Deceased)
            values (@parishid,@yearid,@monthid,@total)

        end

        else
        begin
            update ParishStatistics 
            set Deceased=@total 
            where Parish_id=@parishid and Year_id=@yearid  and month_id=@monthid
        end

        update ParishStatistics 
        set AnnualDeceased=@gtotal
        where Parish_id=@parishid and Year_id=@yearid

END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @yearid=i.year_id from inserted i` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Pls can you explain by giving me an example of how i will get it done. the issue here is that  the data get inserted into the database but i get an error message after the inserted data. how do i get the error message out.

Comment: Stop using those variables that select values from one random row, treat inserted as a table and join to it!